# Usual augmentation filtration? (Sigma algebra generated by a descreasing family of sets)?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

My aim is to understand the usual augmentation filtration, for example as given 
in the appendix in the book 
*Financial Derivatives in Theory and Practice: Revised Edition* by
P.J. Hunt and J.E. Kennedy.

> Let $(\Omega,{\cal F}^\circ,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability triple.
>   The $\mathbb{P}$-completion $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mathbb{P})$ of
>   $(\Omega,{\cal F}^\circ,\mathbb{P})$ is the probability triple
>   defined by ${\cal F}=\sigma({\cal F}^\circ \cup {\cal N})$, where
>   $${\cal N}:=\{A\subset \Omega: A\subseteq B\mbox{ for some }B\in{\cal F}^\circ\mbox{ with }\mathbb{P}(B)=0\}.$$
>
> The usual augmentation $(\Omega,\{{\cal F}_t\},{\cal F},\mathbb{P})$
>   of the filtered probability space 
>   $(\Omega,\{{\cal F}^\circ_t\},{\cal F}^\circ,\mathbb{P})$
>   is produced by taking ${\cal F}$ to be the $\mathbb{P}$-completion
>   of ${\cal F}^\circ$ and by defining
>   $${\cal F}_t:=\sigma({\cal F}^\circ_{t+}\cup {\cal N}) 
> =\bigcap_{s>t} \sigma({\cal F}^\circ_{s}\cup {\cal N})$$
>   for all $t\geq 0$.

From this, I have a question:

Do we have the following identity?

$$\sigma(\cap_{i \ge 1}C_i)=\cap_{i \ge 1}\sigma(C_i)$$

Here $C_i$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$

and $C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3....$ is a subset of a set Ω.

Comment: Your last two lines contradict each other. It may be useful to recall that $\sigma(C)$ is an intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain $C$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029304/prove-that-sigma-cap-i-in-i-c-i-cap-i-in-i-sigma-c-i